# Jenkins, using withCredentials, how can i authenticate to Git using the SSH private key?

Tags: git, jenkins

The github key is stored in Jenkins. Now I have a  Jenkins job that uses the withCredentials plugin to get that private key like this:

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "my-cred-id", keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
    //auth to git here then do some commands for example:
    sh 'git commmit -am "hello my commit message'
    sh 'git push'
}
```

Now what i want to do is within the withCredentials block to run a few git commands like the example shows above. However, i'm not sure how to use the keyFileVariable in order to authenticate to git so i can run these commands.

Answer (score 2):

Location of the SSH key is copied temporarily into the variable defined in `keyFileVariable`. In your case it is `'key'`. You can access it by `$key`

Then you need to tell git to use the new credentials by setting the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i $key"` So your step becomes:

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "my-cred-id", keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
        //auth to git here then do some commands for example:
        sh 'git commmit -am "hello my commit message'
        sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i $key"'
        sh 'git push'
    }
```

That being said, best practice is to setup the jenkins job once in the beginning and define the git key in repo settings. This is a fairly special use case where the checkout should not use the same credentials as the push.

Comment: thank you @Yamac Kurtulus great answer, I do wonder about what you said with the best practice. Is it better to have a withCredentials with the single line

        sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i $key"'

at the start of the Jenkins job to authenticate the whole job? incase I need to do multiplie commands else in the job?