# How to run a git command with SSH key on jenkins using batch?

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins, ssh

I have a bat script that is run on my jenkins pipeline.

It is used to tag a specific commit of my branch, and push it back to git.
Looks like this:

```
"scriptCommand": https://%C_USERNAME%:%C_PASSWORD%@bitbucket.psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git\ngit push origin TAG1\ngit remote set-url --push origin https://bitbucket..psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git"
```

That command is made using the variables C_USERNAME, C_PASSWORD and the TAG1
The first two are taken from a usernamePassword type jenkins credentials, and are injected into the string, the TAG1 is a stimple string that should be used to get my git branch tagged

And that works, when I use the http link instead of the SSH link for my repo

I need to be able to handle the SSH link as well.
For that, I researched on SSH private key, and turns out that the jenkins credentials have a specific field for it: SSH Username with private key

I made one such credential in jenkins, using my private key, and username

But now I am having trouble on how to create a batch line that works the same as the one above with the http link.

Needless to say, I have 0 exp on this matter.

Can some help me on this? And thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSH URL would be like:

```
git@bitbucket.psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git
```

But you might want to use a dedicated plugin, like [publish over SSH](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin), which you can [include in a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70380580/6309).

In your case:

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@bitbucket.psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git
```

Using an [SSH agent plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)

```sh
node {
  sshagent (credentials: ['myKey']) {
    sh 'git push git@bitbucket.psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git aTag'
  }
}
```

Assuming you have [registered your private key in the Jenkins Global credentials (unrestricted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258029/6309), as an entry named '`myKey`'.

Using [`withCredentials`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/), as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67711781/6309), assuming [Git 2.10+ for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309):

```sh
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "myKey", keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
        //auth to git here then do some commands for example:
        sh 'git commmit -am "hello my commit message'
        sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i $key"'
        sh 'git push git@bitbucket.psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git aTag'
    }
```

Comment: thx for the advise, I will give it a try, but can you tell me how the git command would have too look like if I had to add a tag to an ssh type link?

Comment: @Elydasian "add a tag to an SSH type link"? What do you mean? Like a Host entry in a `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: well, if I would use the line that I posted above in my question would push a tag to my git repo (using http protocol), how would the same line would look like if I were to use the ssh protocol? (I hope this makes sense :))

Comment: @Elydasian OK, got it. the set-url would be: `git remote set-url --push origin git@bitbucket.psr.io/scme/ci/ci.git`

Comment: thx, that worked! Also, I am looking into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377238/use-ssh-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline-with-ssh-scp-or-sftp, posted by tianzhipeng, would you mind taking a look? I am close to implementing the ssh key, but I dont know what is the  keyFileVariable: 'keyfile' used for?

Comment: @Elydasian I would assume an sshAgent step is enough. I have edited the answer to include an example, as well as relevant links to documentation.

Comment: yes, on my side I cannot install the sshagent, how would that example look if you were to use the withCredentials method? Assuming the Credentials Binding Plugin, Credentials Plugin are present? (I have quite a bit of logic in this, and I need to use it with those plugins)

Comment: @Elydasian OK. I have edited the answer to add the version using `withCredentials`.

Comment: YESSSSS, thank you very much!! Just tell me, whats that keyFileVariable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244054/discussion-between-vonc-and-elydasian).

Comment: Hello @VonC, im using withCredentials, but i get this error "fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var)"

Comment: @dssof That means the job did not checkout a Git repository. Try and ask a separate question with more details on your Jenkins setup and job configuration.