# Pushing git tag to ssh protocol type link failes in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a repo: https://github.com/Elydasian/gatling-example

I have a pipeline in jenkins ready, that checks out that repo, and after some building and whatnot, I want to tag the branch.

I made a "SSH Username with private key" credentials and added it to my jenkins pipeline
Now, I am finished doing what I needed with it (I checkout the project)

Now I need to be able to TAG it.
For that, I have done the following lines:

```
git tag TAG_NAME
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:Elydasian/gatling-example.git 
git push origin TAG_NAME
```

Then, it throws an error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This is a basic ssh error; it has nothing in particular to do with Git and definitely nothing to do with the use of a tag. You just need to set up your ssh keys so that when `git push` runs `ssh`, the connection works. (Pay attention to the system's idea of who is running ssh, since that determines where `ssh` gets its default keys, and to the ssh configuration in that user's `.ssh/config` and to any ssh agent that may be in use and so on: all the usual ssh things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the right key is read.

From your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71897666/6309), that what `sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i $key"'` was for in the [`withCredentials` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).

In your case, try `git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -Tv' push origin TAG_NAME` instead of just `git push`, in order to see what key it is trying to use.

---

The [OP Elydasian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4966403/elydasian) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71957589/pushing-git-tag-to-ssh-protocol-type-link-failes-in-jenkins/71958138#comment127320567_71958138):

> At the end, the problem was not the code, but **server permissions**, as my pipeline was running multiple commands on multiple servers (only one of them had my credentials SSH key).
>
> **The solution was to split my pipeline to work only on one server.**

Comment: @torek Thank you for the edit, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi again, yes, your last code made me come this far, but this line you suggested (git -c core.ssh...) throws an error: 

git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -Tv' push origin TAG_NAME
unknown option: -Tv'
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [--super-prefix=<path>] [--config-env=<name>=<envvar>]
           <command> [<args>]

Comment: @Elydasian What is your shell (where you are typing this command)? You can also try `="xxx"` instead of `='xxx'`.

Comment: My shell can differ, one is in linux (sh), one is in windows (bat), currently I am using windows. Also, I changed to double quotes, and the command worked. I am looking into it now, it seems that the server is not using my SSH key. I will updated the question once I find the problem. Thanks

Comment: At the end, the problem was not the code, but server permissions. As my pipeline was running multiple commands on multiple servers (only one of them had my credentials SSH key). The solution was to split my pipeline to work only on one server. Thank you for your time and advice anyway, the debugging command helped a lot.

Comment: @Elydasian Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.